# Getting the name of piped unzipped files after grep(ping) a particular string

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a bunch of .epub files and i'm trying to search for a particular string in their .opf files.

I'm getting the right results but i'd also like to see the name of the file containing that string.

```
$ unzip -c '*.epub' | grep -a -H 'dc:date'
```

Comment: try this command once,  `for file in *.epub; do
    unzip -p "$file" '*.opf' 2>/dev/null | grep -a -q 'dc:date' && echo "$file"
done`

Comment: @RajeshP : Post that as an answer with a little explanation (maybe relevant section of `man unzip`) and I"ll upvote it. Good show!

Comment: @RajeshP didn't work, i have to ctrl+C to kill the process.

Comment: @RajeshP It worked with this: 
`for file in *.epub ; do unzip -p "$file" | grep -a -q 'date' && echo "$file" ; done
`

Comment: Might be problem with syntax error missing ";" before done. Good that you found the solution.